# JSON Parse error Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json

i trying to parse JSON with `NSJSONSerialization`.
`NSArray *a = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];` the error shows this: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Badly formed array around character 202.) UserInfo=0x9f79230 {NSDebugDescription=Badly formed array around character 202.}`
here is the JSON code:

```
[
    {
        "ID":1,
        "name":"sometext",
        "c":"sometext",
        "city":"sometext",
        "street":"sometext",
        "a":32.914671,
        "b":35.292417,
        "Info":"sometext",
        "imageAddress":"images/aroma.jpeg"
    }
    {
        "ID":2,
        "name":"sometext",
        "c":"sometext",
        "city":"sometext",
        "street":"sometext",
        "a":4.224,
        "b":72.1234,
        "Info":"sometext",
        "imageAddress":"images/"
    }
```

where the JSON not coded currently?

Comment: Your JSON is not ended properly, Validate your json here - jsonlint.org

Comment: Maybe the missing `]`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because JSON linters and parsers exist.

Comment: and there's obviously a `,` missing between the two dictionaries. Come on, try something before making a question...

Comment: its not Badly formed array..it is Badly formed json from you.

Comment: @theShay Missing comma! Always check commas, golden rule...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JSON, array objects are not separated by `comma`

```
[
    {
        "ID":1,
        "name":"sometext",
        "c":"sometext",
        "city":"sometext",
        "street":"sometext",
        "a":32.914671,
        "b":35.292417,
        "Info":"sometext",
        "imageAddress":"images/aroma.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "ID":2,
        "name":"sometext",
        "c":"sometext",
        "city":"sometext",
        "street":"sometext",
        "a":4.224,
        "b":72.1234,
        "Info":"sometext",
        "imageAddress":"images/"
    }
]
```

This should work.

Comment: you can validate your JSON using http://jsonlint.com/